# Present and present continues

Tags: present-tense, present-continuous

Difference between the following:

A) When does she go to office?

B) At what time, she goes to office?

C) When is she going to office?

Comment: The sentences 1 and 2 convey the same meaning, asking about his routine, regular time of his going to office, whereas the sentence 3 indicates a particular event in the future that means 'When will he go to office?'

Answer (score 2):

Version **A)** implies recurrence.  You might as well have asked, "When does she *typically* go to the office?"

Version **B)** is grammatically incorrect, but could be adjusted to read as follows: "At what time does she go to the office?"  In that case, the implied meaning is identical to version A.

Version **C)** also needs a slight adjustment: "When is she going to the office?" This version implies that you are inquiring about a specific occurrence, or even that you are waiting on the event to happen.

Answer (score 0):

1. Present simple indicates repetition, routine, habits. She most likely goes there every day or going to office is part of a strict pattern.
2. The comma after *At what time* is incorrect. This conveys similar meaning to the first one. However, some emphasis has been put to the concept of her schedule, we are more interested in what time exactly do she goes there.
3. This time we either have evidence that she is, in fact, going to office right now, or that going there was her personal intention for some time.

EDIT: As macserv stated, the second question is incorrect. I haven't seen that coming, sorry :)